# Unable to parse a JSON in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

I am trying to parse a JSON object that comes in from mongodb but am unable to use it for some reason after parsing.

Here is the piece of javascript function that I am using

```
 -function check(category) {
      -var temp = JSON.stringify(category);
      -return JSON.parse(temp);

  -}

.row.wow.fadeInRight.animated(data-wow-offset='30', data-wow-duration='1.5s', data-wow-delay='0.15s')
        .col-md-12
           if(articles)
              #client-feedbacks.owl-carousel.owl-theme
               each article in articles
                -var category = article.categories
                .feedback-box
                  .client-image.hidden-xs
                      img(src=article._.image.fit(250,250), alt='article image')
                  // MESSAGE OF THE CLIENT
                  h6.article-title
                    a(href='/blog/post/' + article.slug, itemprop='url')!= article.title
                  br
                  .message!= article.content.brief
                  // CLIENT INFORMATION
                  .client
                    .quote.red-text
                      i.icon-fontawesome-webfont-294
                    .client-info
                      a.client-namea(href='/blog/post/' + article.slug, itemprop='url')!= prettyDate(article.publishedDate)
                      -var categories = check(category)
                      .client-company(itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting") #{category[0].name}
```

Here is what the object looks like when i use json .stringify

```
    { updatedBy: 5498631c5cbfa2d03f4570e6,
  updatedAt: Mon Feb 09 2015 00:30:48 GMT+0530 (IST),
  createdBy: 5498631c5cbfa2d03f4570e6,
  createdAt: Mon Feb 09 2015 00:30:48 GMT+0530 (IST),
  key: 'mongoose',
  name: 'Mongoose',
  _id: 54d7b2601d88fc4f69d0e081,
  __v: 0 },{ updatedBy: 5498631c5cbfa2d03f4570e6,
  updatedAt: Mon Feb 09 2015 00:31:44 GMT+0530 (IST),
  createdBy: 5498631c5cbfa2d03f4570e6,
  createdAt: Mon Feb 09 2015 00:31:44 GMT+0530 (IST),
  key: 'green-berrets',
  name: 'Green Berrets',
  _id: 54d7b298fe85a1c4698b2ec3,
  __v: 0 }
```

I am confused on how to parse it as most of the things i tried did not work

Comment: you should never parse data in your jade templates, do it from the outer scope and pass the data to the jade template as __locals__. see http://jade-lang.com/api/ for instance  `var fn = jade.compile('string of jade', options);
var html = fn(locals);`